# Hot to set the working directory of a process in Java

Tags: java, directory

I am trying to set the working directory of a process that will be running an exe.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public Process launchClient() throws IOException {
    File pathToExecutable = new File(currentAccount.getAbsoluteFile()+"/Release", "TuringBot.exe");
    System.out.println(pathToExecutable);
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(pathToExecutable.getAbsolutePath());
    builder.directory( new File( currentAccount, "Release" )); // this is where you set the root folder for the executable to run with
    System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
              System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    return builder.start();
}
```

but every time I launch it, the exe attempts to run but fails to because the current directory is wrong and it can't properly access the required files.

EDIT:

Here's a little more about whats going on...
I have x amount of client folders, each contains an executable file that needs to be started and relies on the contents of its local folder to execute properly, however when running this code to launch each executable file the working path for each unique executable is not being applied and is rather the default directory (the JAR's locations).

Comment: Is the value of `currentAccount+"/Release"` correct?

Comment: Yes, I print to the console to ensure this

Comment: Well, write a small script that prints the current working directory and test this again.

Comment: It should be `new File(currentAccount, "/Release")` of course.

Comment: @EJP You meant `new File(currentAccount, "Release")`

Comment: Updated code to apply comments, but even when exported as a runnable JAR and placed in what should be the proper path, it is still using the JAR's folder location as the working directory. Is there a way I can achieve this easier through Runtime/cmd?

Comment: Added more in depth information as to what the problem is here. Thank you.